# Blender 3d Не корректное затенение

Tags: 3d, blender

Экспортировал модель из fuse в blender не прогоняя через сайт анимированные mixamo?
И сначала когда импортировал получил вот такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Отключил прозрачность думаю плевать для бровей отделений материал сделаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Прозрачность поборол но тени некорректно, нормали как только не пытался выворачивать комбинацией ALT N  не помогло
Если подключить напрямую картинка к выводу то вроде норм пока прозрачность не включить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Удалил полностью материал и понял что проблема именно в меше, но не пойму как исправить помогите пожалуйста. Все импорты из fuse такие если не пропускать через сайт mixamo но это решение не очень.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[Модель](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S5h6rhIEdziXa9klDP74VhekGsiU7KGT/view?usp=sharing) Blender 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нажмите здесь **clear custom split normal data**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]